# How can i git-cherry-picks with respect to date(order) of commits?

Tags: git

If i cherry-picks the commit frome remote branch it became on top of my current branch, so the order commits are applayed changing and i got incorrect results. How can i cherry-picks commit from remote branch with respect to date (when it was applyed in remote branch), so commits would be not in top of my current branch but in the right place by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cherry-picks always end up at the tip of a branch (and in the order given to the command). If you want another result, `git cherry-pick` isn't the tool you should be looking at.

From your description, it sounds like you have the following situation:

```
  F---G---H---I    origin/master
 /
A---B---C---D---E  master
```

From origin/master, you want to cherrypick commits, say, F and H, but not onto the tip of the branch but somewhere in between, perhaps like this:

```
  F---G---H---I              origin/master
 /
A---B---F'---C---H'---D---E  master
```

There are several ways of obtaining this state. The following examples creates a new branch from B and cherrypicks the commits in the desired order and finally recreates the master branch with a rename operation that overwrites the original branch.

```
$ git checkout -b newmaster B
$ git cherry-pick F C H D E
$ git branch -M newmaster master
```

If you have a larger number of commits you probably want to automate things with e.g. `git rev-list`, but it's hard to give advice without knowing more about the situation.

You mention date a few times. While Git does record two types of timestamps for a commit, none are likely to be useful in your case. When cherry-picking changes from other branches the primary concern is the branch topology, i.e. the fact that commit H comes after commit G which comes after commit F. Topology comparisons between branches, like origin/master and master in my example above, are not possible. In other words, it's not possible to determine the correct order of the cherry-picks without actually trying to apply the patches.